# Excel 2007 Display image from image path?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, export-to-excel, vba

I would like to insert an image into a cell.
The code below inserts it into a sheet:

```
            With wb.Sheets(1).Pictures.Insert("\\bk01fil0001\salesdb$\ImageUpload\NoImage.gif")
            .Left = wb.Sheets(1).Range("B2").Left
            .Top = wb.Sheets(1).Range("B2").Top
            .Width = wb.Sheets(1).Range("B2").Width
            End With
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking? Does code you posted not work correctly?

Comment: Try a Google search for: "insert image into a cell excel vba".  Tons of info out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't insert a picture **inside** a cell: they always sit "on top" of the worksheet.  Best you can do is position it over the required cell/range as you are already doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can make things a little simpler by selecting a cell then inserting the picture...

```
Sheets(1).Select
Range("B2").Select
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("\\bk01fil0001\salesdb$\ImageUpload\NoImage.gif")
```

I don't think this would ever be a less efficient method as you would only ever wish to insert a picture on a visible sheet. I do not see you would need to select the sheet more than once, if at all

(As an aside, it sounds as though you are trying to auto-insert images in one column of a table in which case I would strongly recommend using Cells notation as described in the text accompanying this [Excel Visual Basic video](http://www.excel4business.com/videos/introduction-vba-macros.php))